# Function omission using template meta-programming?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm just starting to learn template meta-programming, and I'm trying to understand its limitations.

Take for example the following `triangle_t` class:

```
struct triangle_t
{
    triangle_t() { }
    triangle_t(vec3_t  v0, vec3_t  v1, vec3_t  v2) : v0(v0), v1(v1), v2(v2) { }

    vec3_t v0;
    vec3_t  v1;
    vec3_t  v2;

    vec3_t  normal();
};
```

Now, triangles can be 2 and 3-dimensional, so maybe I want to make this a templated class, like so:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T>
    struct triangle_t
    {
        triangle_t() { }
        triangle_t(T v0, T v1, T v2) : v0(v0), v1(v1), v2(v2) { }

        T v0;
        T v1;
        T v2;

        T normal();
    };
};

typedef detail::triangle_t<vec2_t> triangle2_t;
typedef detail::triangle_t<vec3_t> triangle3_t;
```

Everything's all fine and dandy so far, except one problem.  2-dimensional triangles do not have normals.  So what I want to do is, by way of template meta-programming, omit the `normal()` function for the `triangle2_t` struct.

I attempted to perform the following implementation:

```
template<typename U = T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, vec3_t>::value, U>::type normal() const
{
    return glm::cross((v1 - v0), (v2 - v0));
}
```

I received this error:

> error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class
>   template

Is what I'm attempting to do possible?  If not, are there any similar methods that can deliver the same result?

Comment: Default function arguments are legal in C++11, but MSVC11 doesn't support them, and I can't remember if MSVC12 does.

Comment: I'm using MSVC12 right now.

Comment: Why exactly do you need the default template parameter?

Comment: Not sure, I was just copying some things I found on the internet that looked like they were trying to do the same thing I was. :P

Comment: The 2012 CTP and the VS2013 compiler support default function arguments. You need them here to make the instantiation of the function template fail w/o passing explicit template arguments in the function call.

Comment: Note that the `is_same` here defeats the intent of *generic* programming: It only works for exact matches, whereas for all vector types with dimension > 2, the `normal` function should be available.

Comment: (Yet another independent comment ;) If you just want to support 2- and 3d vectors, `T normal();` (w/o any checks) should be sufficient, if `glm::cross` can only be compiled for 3d vectors. The definition of a member (like a member function) is instantiated on-demand (and not with the class), so the program would only fail to compile if `normal()` is called on a 2d-vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `normal` non-member function.

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, vec3_t>::value, T>::type normal(triangle_t<T> const& t)
{
    return glm::cross((t.v1 - t.v0), (t.v2 - t.v0));
}
```

or better yet (no tmp needed)

```
vec3_t normal(triangle_t<vec3_t> const& t)
{
    return glm::cross((t.v1 - t.v0), (t.v2 - t.v0));
}
```

Comment: +1 For pointing out that [a member function is not required here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197).

Comment: This is an elegant solution, thank you. :)  I guess since I'm just learning about TMP, I want to solve all kinds of problems using it.  What's the old saying?  "When you're a hammer, every problem looks like a nail"? :P

Answer (score 0):

I probably would do:

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename T>
    struct triangle_t
    {
        triangle_t() { }
        triangle_t(T v0, T v1, T v2) : v0(v0), v1(v1), v2(v2) { }

        T v0;
        T v1;
        T v2;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct triangle_with_normal_t : triangle_t<T>
    {
        // constructors here
        T normal();
    };

};

typedef detail::triangle_t<vec2_t> triangle2_t;
typedef detail::triangle_with_normal_t<vec3_t> triangle3_t;
```

But this is not necessarily TMP.